# How to return username instead of user object in DRF?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to set a username for each object. Here is my models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings


# Tweet Model
class TweetModel(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(max_length=300, blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

And viewset.py

```
from .models import TweetModel
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions


# TweetViewset
class TweetViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated
    ]
    serializer_class = TweetSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        ordered = TweetModel.objects.order_by('-created_at')
        return ordered

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user, username=self.request.user.username)
```

But it is not working. Error is

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column tweets_tweetmodel.username does not exist
LINE 1: ...el"."created_at", "tweets_tweetmodel"."owner_id", "tweets_tw...
```

Can you help, please?

Comment: Did you run `manage.py makemigrations` and then `migrate`?

Comment: I bet that he didn't run the command `makemigrations` and `migrate` before ^^

Comment: It is working now, I forgot to migrate. Thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to run `makemigrations` and `migrate`